# Is it possible to add another columns in Datatable export function?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatable to output my list. In my HTML list there are few columns the other column that are not important is hidden.
Is it possible in the export function for include those columns? And other question is how can I print PDF in landscape mode?

Here's my code:

**My JSON data**

```
$data['data'][] = array(
                    ($con['contract_ext'] != '') ? '<a href="' . site_url('contracts/contracts/edit_contract_phase1?contract_id=' . $con['id']) . '" class="btn-link">'. $con['contract_id'] . '-' . $con['contract_ext'] . '</a>' : '<a href="' . site_url('contracts/contracts/edit_contract_phase1?contract_id=' . $con['id']) . '" class="btn-link">' . $con['contract_id'] . '</a>',
                    '<span class="txt_small">' . $client['client_name'] . '</span>',
                    $con['contract_type'],
                    format_mysql_time($con['date_added'], 'm/d/Y - H:i:s'),
                    format_mysql_time($con['date_modified'], 'm/d/Y H:i:s'),
                    $added_by['name'],
                    $con['status'],
                    '<a data-toggle="modal"  href="javascript:;" data-target="#myModal" data-id="' . $con['id'] . '" id="contract-' .  $con['id']. '" class="btn btn-sm btn-default contract_modal" type="button"><span class="fa fa-paperclip"></span></a> ' .
                    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onClick="addRemark(' . $con['id'] . ')"><span class="fa fa-comment-o"></span></button> ' .
                    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button>'

                );
```

**My JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#contract-list').DataTable({
    "ajax": "<?php echo site_url('contracts/contracts/load_contracts'); ?>",

    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ],
    "order": [],
        "columnDefs": [ {
          "targets"  : 'no-sort',
          "orderable": false,
        }]
    });
</script>
```

I hope you can help me with this

Answer (score 0):

By default Datatables will export all columns in a table. I've got a feeling that what ever you are doing to hide the columns is not supported. What you should do is hide the columns that you don't need with a Datatables supported method. In this example I am making two columns hidden:

```
columnDefs: [{targets: [4, 5], visible: false}]
```

As for making PDFs landscape, there is an option against the button for this:

```
{extend: 'pdf', orientation: 'landscape'}
```

Here it is all put together for you. Remember to remove your column hiding logic and instead update the list of columns in the 'targets' option for visibility of columnDefs below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#contract-list').DataTable({
        "ajax": "<?php echo site_url('contracts/contracts/load_contracts'); ?>",

        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', {extend: 'pdf', orientation: 'landscape'}, 'print'
        ],
        "order": [],
        "columnDefs": [
            {"targets": 'no-sort', "orderable": false},
            {"targets": [4, 5], visible: false}
        ]
    }
</script>
```